# For loop with an array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a[5];
  for (int i = -1; i < 7; i++)
    cout << i << " " << setw(2) << a[i] << endl;

}
```

So I'm trying to figure out why this won't work. If i take out a[i] it works, but if i leave it in, the for loop goes from -2 until the 1000's which is obviously not right. Is it because a[i] is not bound to the parameters of the for loop (i < 7)? I'm not really sure I understand.

**EDIT** As many of you have explained it was a matter of **uninitializing the array** and **using bounds outside of the array** (e.g -2). It was not something I thought of, nor found when searching for why this was happening.

Comment: Doesn't look like `a` is being initialized.

Comment: `a[-1]`, `a[5]` and `a[6]` are accessing `a` out of bounds. That is undefined behavior.

Comment: You have two kinds of undefined behavior here: accessing invalid indices in an array, and using uninitialized values.  "Not working" is no surprise (but nothing's guaranteed).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Memory for `a` has only been allocated from `a` -> `a+4` , not `a-1` -> `a+6`. And automatically allocated primitives are not initialised by default, you should be compiling with warnings on; you've invoked ub, so... be afraid :)

Comment: Do you realize that in order to go from -1 to 7, you need at least 7 elements in the array?  You declared it with 5.  I recommend adding an offset to your index so the first slot is at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

First, as marcadian pointed out, the array `a` is not initialized, so values in the array are completely random.

Also, the size of the `a` array is 5, meaning that you can access between indexes 0 and 4 inclusive.

However, in your loop, you try to access at index -1, and index 6. Attempting to write and read at invalid indexes ( such as -1 and 6, in this case ) is undefinded behavior ( it can crash with a segmentation fault, or corrupt other variables, which can make debugging process very hard ... )

A way to avoid buffer overrun like you did is to use `std::array` STL container, like this :

```
std::array<int, 5> a;
//Access elements using the method 'at()', it has bound checking
a.at(0); // 0 is a valid index
//a.at(-1); // -1 is not a valid index, it will crash ( at least in debug mode )
//a.at(6); // 6 is also not a valid index
```

The `std::array` STL container does the same things normal array does, but provides useful methods

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out random value in memory because variable `a` is not initialized. Uninitialized variable has random value in memory. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

in computers an array is really just a given number of values, starting at array[0], and ending at array[n].
`int a[5];` statically allocates space for **5** integers on the stack, starting at a[0], and ending at a[4].
Try this iteration instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not initializing the array, a, the indices you would be using to access its elements are out of bounds. C++ uses zero-indexing - you could try, for instance:

```
int main()  {  
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {    
        cout << i << " " << a[i] << endl;  
    }
}
```

Output would be:
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5